# bash + compare variable with spaces

Tags: shell-script, variable, string, test

I want to print the **firewall-cmd --state** status in variable - $STAT

and then compare the variable $STAT with "not running" string

but Comparison get false , it is because spaces inside the variable

please advice how to do it bash regular expiration

so I will check that "not running" contain in the variable so will print the "not running" by echo

```
#  firewall-cmd --state
   not running
   STAT=` firewall-cmd --state `
   echo $STAT
   not running
   [[ $STAT = "not running" ]] && echo "not running"

   no output
```

Comment: Instead of `echo $STAT`, do `printf "%q\n" "$STAT"` so you can see *exactly* what's in it. This is necessary because `=` is exact string equality operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works just fine:

```
$ stat=$(echo "not running")
$ [[ $stat = "not running" ]] && echo yes
yes
```

However, if you get leading or trailing spaces in the variable, it doesn't work. But you could use a pattern match or a regex match to cover for that:

```
$ stat=$(echo " not running ")
$ [[ $stat = *"not running"* ]] && echo yes
yes
$ [[ $stat =~ "not running" ]] && echo yes
yes
```

Both search for the string `not running` within the variable. The asterisks in the first one explicitly account for leading or trailing characters. The second is regex match which by default looks for a match anywhere within the string.

To match against leading or trailing spaces explicitly with a regex, it's easiest to put the regex in a variable. `$pattern` must be *unquoted* in the conditional.

```
$ pattern="^ *not running *$"
$ [[ $stat =~ $pattern ]] && echo yes
yes
```

(I assumed only possible extra space characters here, not arbitrary whitespace.)

Comment: For regex, use `[[:space:]]*` instead. That will match any whitespace, not just spaces.

Comment: @glennjackman, yeah, if there's a chance of tabs or such. Trailing newlines shouldn't be a problem since the command substitution will eat them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use quotes.

If the output of `firewall-cmd --state` is `not running`, then the command `STAT=$( firewall-cmd --state )` will set the variable `STAT` to the string `not`, and then try to execute `running`.

What you want to do is:

```
STAT="$( firewall-cmd --state )"
```

You can do all of this at once without using a variable:

```
if [[ "not running" = "$( firewall-cmd --state )" ]]; then
    echo "It's not running"
else
    echo "It's running"
fi
```

Comment: +1 just for the good programming practice of putting the constant on the left of the equals sign.

Comment: shell assignment doesn't need quotes, and neither does `[[ .. ]]`. try something like `bash -c 'stat=$(echo "not running"); [[ $stat = "not running" ]] && echo yes`

Comment: @JeffSchaller, that only applies to languages where assignments work in arbitrary expressions, and for compilers that are dumb enough not to warn about it.

Comment: please advice why this not works ??  - [[ "not running" =~ $STAT ]]  or [[ "not running" =~ "$STAT" ]]

Comment: It's still good practice to put the constant on the LHS, just so that you don't have to think about whether you're in a context where it matters or not.  As to quotes, I may have been mistaken about _needing_ them, but similarly, I tend to err on the side of "quote everything" out of an abundance of caution.